# Vuetify <v-text-field> clears input after clicking on result from Google Maps autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-places-api, vuetify.js

I have a page which contains a `<v-text-field>` and I have added GoogleMaps autocomplete support to it.
However, it seems like Vuetify clears the input after the user selects an address.

I found out that the issue is related to the input's `blur` event.

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue and allow the address to remain in the input?

He's a working example of the issue on Codepen: https://codepen.io/jfmachado01/full/YRMpVL/

```
<v-text-field
  id="autocomplete"
  prepend-icon="place"
  placeholder="Address"
>
```

And here's a GIF of the issue:
[Disabling the javascript blur event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz7jV.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the google maps autocomplete is meant to be used more in a `jquery` way, but if you want to use it inside Vue, you'll have to use `v-model` and an address variable to make the value not disappear:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="address" // this will sync the address value in data and the component
  id="autocomplete"
  prepend-icon="place"
  placeholder="Address"
>
```

Then in the script part of your code:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      address: '', // add this data variable
      states: [],
      autocomplete: null,
    }
  },

  // inside the mounted hook:
  this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    var place = self.autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.address = place.name; // update the value
  });
```